# Translate SQL sub-select in qlik script

Tags: qlikview

I have a SQL script like this

```
select TranDate,
       ID,
       StatusID
       coalesce(
                (select top 1 StatusID from Customer c2 where c1.ID = C2.ID and c1.TranDate <= c2.TranDate),
                7
               ) as NextStatus
from Customer c
```

And I'm sorry that I don't have any idea of how to make it work, I only have the `Load` script for the `Customer`

```
[Customer]:
Load [TranDate], [ID], [StatusID]
FROM [lib://user/test2.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is Customer);
```

Comment: Does that SQL script create the test2.xlsx Excel sheet that you're reading from in Qlik?

Comment: Nope, the `test2.xlsx` only have that 3 fields.  So that I want to do that in Qlik, otherwise, I may need to manually handle in the Excel, that's the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

you case use it as follow :
Data:
Load [TranDate], [ID], [StatusID];
SQL select ...(your sql query);

that's all